# Getting module from string parameter

Tags: sass

I'm trying to get a module name from a string. Here is an example of what I imagine it would look like:

```css
@use 'dark'; /* _dark.scss, with a $color variable */
@use 'light'; /* _light.scss, with a $color variable */

@mixin theme($name) {
  body {
    color: #{$name}.$color;
  }
}
```

If I passed in `"dark"` as an argument, I would want this result:

```css
...
color: dark.$color;
...
```

If I passed in `"light"` as an argument, I would want this result:

```css
...
color: light.$color;
...
```